# Delete first blank line

Tags: vba, ms-word

I made a simple userform to insert certain text based on whether certain clickboxes are checked. Shortened version below. Problem is that, as my code is currently written, if cbx1 isn't clicked but cbx2 is, then the string that gets pasted in leads with a new line. Is there a simple way to just add at the end something like "If [first line of strNewText] = vbNewLine[?] Then [delete first line of strNewText]"? A better solution? Thanks!

```
Private Sub cmdInsert_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim strToAdd As String

Dim text1 As String
Dim text2 As String
Dim text2 As String

text1 = "This is Text 1."
text2 = "This is Text 2."
text3 = "This is Text 3."

If cbx1 = True Then strToAdd = text1
If cbx2 = True Then strToAdd = strToAdd & vbNewLine & text2
If cbx3 = True Then strToAdd = strToAdd & vbNewLine & text3

With ActiveDocument
    Selection.Text = strToAdd
    Selection.Collapse
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would flip the logic a little bit and add the vbNewLine on the end.  This way, no matter the combination of checkmarks I know the string always ends with a vbNewLine.  Then it is a simple matter to remove the trailing vbNewLine.  This approach also keeps the code a little more concise:

```
If cbx1 = True Then strToAdd = strToAdd & text1 & vbNewLine
If cbx2 = True Then strToAdd = strToAdd & text2 & vbNewLine
If cbx3 = True Then strToAdd = strToAdd & text3 & vbNewLine
If Len(strToAdd) > 0 Then strToAdd = Mid(strToAdd, 1, Len(strToAdd) - 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Iif`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function) function to test whether `strToAdd` contains any text before adding a new line.

```
Private Sub cmdInsert_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim strToAdd As String

    Dim text1 As String
    Dim text2 As String
    Dim text3 As String

    text1 = "This is Text 1."
    text2 = "This is Text 2."
    text3 = "This is Text 3."

    If cbx1 = True Then strToAdd = text1
    If cbx2 = True Then strToAdd = strToAdd & IIf(strToAdd = vbNullString, "", vbNewLine) & text2
    If cbx3 = True Then strToAdd = strToAdd & IIf(strToAdd = vbNullString, "", vbNewLine) & text3

    With ActiveDocument
        Selection.Text = strToAdd
        Selection.Collapse
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I get why this should work but when I try it it's also deleting all the vbNewLines between the sentences. In other words, if I click just cbx2 and cbx3, it pastes in "This is Text 2.This is Text3." without the line in between. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @scorpiomurtlock - It works perfectly for me in all scenarios.